# On Click use jQuery to Show Content

Tags: jquery, click

I have a homepage slider that is attached to links to specific sections of a page (ex. href="/index.php#ene-drop). This section is hidden by default. I would like to write some code so on click it goes to the correct URL and then shows the appropriate section. If I just write this the code executes while on the first page and not the second.

```
  $('#slider-nav .description a').click(function() {
    $('#ene-drop').slideToggle('medium');
  });
```

I know there has to be something that says "Wait to run this code until the href is executed" or something like that. Thanks for the help. Let me know if it would help to post more code.

Answer (score 2):

This is the code you will put on the **destination** page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    if (location.hash == "#enedrop") { // This will only run if the adress has is "something#enedrop"
        $('#active-ene-drop').slideToggle('medium');
    }
});
```

Comment: This is what I would have suggested. A query string parameter that a jquery .ready() function can check for.

Comment: So can I put this in the application.js file or does it have to go inside of the destination page? (I generally like to keep my JS apart from my HTML)

Comment: Both ways will work. However, you should leave it on the page if it is only good for that single page. You should use external javascript only to make your code more DRY, otherwise it is simply an additional request to the server.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to another page and then want js to execute on that page `.click()` probably won't work. What you will want to do is when that next page loads execute some js on the element you want to drop down.

So in your js you need something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 // Handler for .ready() called.
 $('#active-ene-drop').slideToggle('medium');
});
```

When it goes to the next page, when the DOM is ready it will slide toggle the `#active-ene-drop` element. You are going to need a way to make sure only the ones you want to have the effect will have that id. Might want to use classes instead.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for an AJAX solution:

HTML:

```
<a href="index.php#section1">Load section 1</a>
<a href="index.php#section2">Load section 2</a>
```

JS:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('href').split('#').join(' #');

    $('#content-div').load(url, function(){
        $(this).slideToggle('medium');
    });
});
```

HTML of index.php:

```
<div id="section1">
    ...
</div>
<div id="section2">
    ...
</div>
```